# Resolving two 3-Way Switches for two separate lights on one Combination Switch

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

I am now attempting to wire two existing three way toggle switches to a Leviton 5643 three way combination switch for two 3-way lights on the same circuit - Pictures included.

Box 1 is what I term the “main box” because it is next to the remote for the fan.
It is important to know that the fan needs continual power so the remote will work.
We can turn the fan/light on and off with both three way switches located at box 1 and 2
Box 1 holds one three way switch
2 gang Box 2 holds two three way switches
In Box 2 - Switch 1 (left switch) works with the fan/light
In Box 2 - Switch 2 (right switch) works with the foyer light

After much work and testing I found the following.

Box 1 is providing the power to the ceiling fan/light.
Box 2 is providing the power to box 1.

I ran a new wire to the 2 gang Box 2 to handle the recessed lighting.
I will leave the wiring for box 1 as is for the ceiling fan/light.
I will be adding a new 15a Leviton Decora 3-way combination switch to handle the power to and from the ceiling fan/light and foyer light.
TOTALLY LOSING MY MIND NOW!
I attempted to wire things as instructed by the combination three way switch and it tripped the breaker. I un wired everything just to see what is happening and found it odd that I was getting power from the Foyer three way wires when I have everything unconnected.

Below is Box 2 showing all of the unconnected wires except for the neutrals.
This box held two three way toggles. I added a new 14/2 wire for the dimmer.
[image: Unconnected wires! The travelers to the foyer have power]

Below is box 1 with 3-way toggle.
[image: Box 1 3 way toggle Switch]

Below is the inside of box 1 showing two wires (one 14/3 and one 14/2).
The 3 way wire goes over to box 2 and the 14/2 wire goes to the ceiling fan/light.
[image: Old Wiring]

Below shows the old wiring for Box 2
[image: Old three way toggle switches]

Below shows the old wiring with the two 3 way toggles in place. Not sure why the black wires are wrapped around the two sets of travelers?
[image: Inside of secondary switch box (NOTE: Four different Romex)]

Below is the wiring image I used to illustrate my situation. Obviously the wiring shown may not reflect what I have because the box 2 on the right only reflects one 3 way toggle switch.
[image: new wiring at Box 2]

Two gang box from inside the closet.
[image]

Comment: Is the power in the switch box, or in the ceiling box?

Comment: **Without disconnecting any wires**, pull the existing switches out of the the box and take pictures showing all the wires/cables going to all the switches.

Comment: Can you *please* post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the other switch box for this fan/light combo please?

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- which box does power enter the circuit at, btw?

Comment: No wonder electricians charge a lot. :-/

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- how attached are you to your current fan remote? Would changing fan controllers be an option?

Comment: The fan/light has a receiver and as you know the wall remote in question communicates with that receiver. It is not wired to any power source (uses a 2032 battery). However, and I can move the remote to any location. Without that controller I would not be able to control the fan/light. I am not against having one wall switch and the other switch replaced by the dimmer. Losing the ability to control the fan power with both switches isn't a big deal to me if that's what I am forced to do.

Comment: What is on your mind?

Comment: I think I have this figured out.
Let me know if my drawing will work.
If not please explain why and if possible provide an updated diagram.
I really appreciate your assistance and constructive criticism

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- your drawing did not post

Comment: @ChristopherLond What exactly are you changing (are you just wanting to add a dimmer to the lights)?  Also, please add titles to the images so we know what box is which.

Comment: No, the Dimmer is set. I had to run a separate 14/2 wire to handle that load. 
The issue is the 2 three way toggles being replaced by a new Model #R42-05643-0WS
Leviton switch.

Answer (score 2):

### Check your box fill

Your plan to feed the recessed lighting from and mount its dimmer at the existing two-gang where power comes in is a good one, save for one issue: *box fill*.  You see, the NEC allocates a given amount of space for wires and devices in boxes to avoid overcrowding and its consequent issues with wire-bending and overheating.  In particular, you have 18 wires in that box, consisting of 12 current carrying wires, 2 wires' worth of grounds (1 for every 4 grounds), and 4 wires' worth of devices (2 wires per gang * 2 gangs).  For 14AWG wire, this yields 36in³, which is a bit more than your average two gang plastic box holds, as those cube out at 32in³.  So, you'll need to check the fill capacity printed on the inside of your existing two-gang box, and replace it with an extra-large box if it comes up short.

Comment: So I have to remove the exiting box and replace with a three gang? Oh man that is not good. Thanks for the education but my problem with why I am not able to get the double 3-way switch to work is still pressing.

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- you should be able to use an oversize/extra deep 2 gang box (look for one >36in3)

Comment: After further discussion with my wife she has decided that we remove the new double 3-way switch and just go with a single three way switch that powers the ceiling fan/ light.
Remove the 14/3 wire from the box and then disconnect the 14/3 wire from the box in the foyer. Add a single pole switch instead. 
The builder of the house put the 3-way between the living room and the foyer literally about six feet from each other so having a 3-way in the living room makes zero sense.

Comment: After further investigation, I am not able to alter the 3-way wiring in the foyer box.
I don't have a load wire there. The load wire is in Box 2 with all the other wires and the other 14/3 wire used in the foyer. Ugh, this is confusing but very informative if and when I need to do this in the future.

Comment: Box 2 has 3-way switch that no longer will be used leaving me with an "dead" 14/3 wire to the foyer 3-way switch, but not really. I changed the traveler black wire to be my load wire.
Because the load wire to the foyer was also in Box 2, I disconnected both the load wire, including the 14/3 wire in Box 2 and pulled them out of the box. I then connected the traveler black wire coming from the foyer to the load wire that was in Box 2, connected both commons and neutrals, making the single pole wiring I wanted for the foyer.
That removed 7 wires satisfying the too many wires issue.

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- that wire/cable needs to terminate in an accessible junction box instead of dangling in the wall.

Comment: The disconnected three way in the foyer needs to terminate to something even though both ends are disconnected? Why cant both ends be dead and capped off?

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- the capped-off ends still need to be in the box, they can't be floating loose in the wall without a box to contain them

Comment: Ok, so the wires I pulled from the 2 gang box and connected in the wall (other than the red traveler) need to be contained in a junction box? Got it.
The red traveler in the box by the front door that isn't being used is already in a box.

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- yeah, those wires either need to be put back into the existing box or moved out into a new 1 gang box next to the existing box.  Note that if you put a new box in, it must be accessible (i.e. not buried behind drywall!)

Comment: I added a picture. I can add a new single gang box next to the existing box that will hold those wires I pulled from the 2 gang box and it will face inside the closet and I will put a blank face plate on it.

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- yeah, that works as a plan